# How to avoid multiple If Statements in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, null, refactoring, nullable

How to refactor this method?

```java
public String getFirstOrLastNameOrBoth() {
    if (this.getFirstname() != null && this.getLastname() != null) {
        return this.getFirstname() + this.getLastname();
    } else if (this.getFirstname() != null && this.getLastname() == null){
        return this.getFirstname();
    } else if (this.getLastname() != null && this.getFirstname() == null){
        return this.getLastname();
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Refactoring is for working code, that code does not work or even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public String getFirstOrLastNameOrBoth() {
        return (getFirstname() == null ? "" : getFirstname()) 
             + (getLastname() == null ? "" : getLastname());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to invoke getter in the class in order to access a field. Use the field name instead.

Instead of null-checks, you can make use of [`noneNullOrElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)) static method of the `Objects` utility class.

```
return Objects.requireNonNullElse(firstName, "") +
       Objects.requireNonNullElse(lastName, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getFirstOrLastNameOrBoth() {
    if(this.getFirstname() == null && this.getLastname() == null) {
        return "0.0";
    }
    
    return (this.getFirstName() != null ? this.getFirstName() : "") +
            (this.getLastname() != null ? this.getLastname() : "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.getFirstname() != null && this.getLastname() != null) {
   return this.getFirstname() + this.getLastname();
} else {
   return Optional.ofNullable(this.getFirstname()).orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(this.getLastname()).orElseGet(() -> "0.0"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `this` if it is not necessary.
2. Use library methods to work with strings.

`StringUtils.trimToEmpty()` from Apache Commons `org.apache.commons.lang3` can be used here

```java
    public String getFirstOrLastNameOrBoth() {
        return trimToEmpty(getFirstname()) + trimToEmpty(getLastname());
    }
```

Comment: *Don't use `this` if it is necessary.*   That seems like bad advice if you want working code :-)  Yes, I see in reality it's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to transfer the if statements in the get methods, so you can check there whether something is null or not. More specifically:

```
 public String getFirstname() {
    if (firstname != null){
    return firstname;}

    return "";
}

public String getLastname() {
    if (lastname!= null){
        return lastname;}

    return "";
}
public String getFirstOrLastNameOrBoth() {
   return (getFirstname() + " " + getLastname()).trim();
}
```

This way is called the extract method and in this case, you'll be able to check for null not only in the last method but also in the getters. Therefore I think it is safe. I have also used the trim method in order to remove the spaces in the beginning in case the first name is null.